# removing padding from columns in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I want to remove padding from padding from columns in wordpress.

http://codesigners.co.uk/nuala/restaurant/

[image: when adding the images the columns dont line up see image]

[image: should look like this]

looking at the code:

```
.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 15px;  <<<tied making this 0px
    padding-right: 15px;    <<<tied making this 0px
    width: 100%;
}
```

also have tried editing the js_composer.min.css file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all Open visual composer back end page to click on edit page.

[image]
 2. For open settings of row which you want to change click on pencil sign.

[image]
Change settings of visual composer row :
Row Settings > Row Stretch > Stretch row and content (no padding) 
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. How do i get to this setting?

Comment: @ryan  Please see  my recent edit and let me know is it done or  not.